# Self host WebApi Routing issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes, self-hosting

I an hosting a self hosted WebApi, but I am struggling with the routing. I think I configured it all right, but I still get 404 as a result:

That's my configurations:

```
 config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
 name: "DefaultApi",
 routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
 defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, 
                 controller = "Values", action = "Index", });
```

Server init:

```
 string baseAddress = "http://localhost:1243";
    var configuration = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(baseAddress);

    WebApiConfig.Register(configuration);
    _server = new HttpSelfHostServer(configuration);
    _server.OpenAsync().Wait();
```

That's my Controller:

```
 public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
```

In my browser I am trying to navigate:

http://localhost:1243/api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake was in defaults:

defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, 
                 controller = "Values", **action = "Index"** });

I don't have any action in my controller which called Index. So there it is..
It took a while but my colleague spotted it eventually.